# What does "bent in upon its body" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> At once, the spider's leg **bent in upon its body**; it rolled over and began to twitch horribly, rocking from side to side.

I don't understand the phrase "bent in upon". I can't picture what it would be like when the spider's leg bent in upon its body. What's the correct way to understand it?

Quoted from *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of "bend" verb meaning is (past tense and past participle *bent*):

> to move part of your body so that it is not straight or so that you
>   are not upright

So, when the spider's leg bent in upon (on) its body, it may mean its leg bent inside its body, on its abdomen.